Replacement for "Weinmann Symetric"
Can I replace these "Weinmann Symetric" brakes on my city bike with something modern? The rim width is ~25mm. I have only found similar brakes online for road bikes, which do not fit the rim width of my city bike.


Please show a photo of the back of the fork demonstrating the brake nut. Are you also planning on replacing the rear brake at the same time?

Is there something wrong with your current brakes?

I will only replace the front brake which has a broken lever. In the back there is a coaster break.

why not replace just the lever?

You are looking for brakes called "long reach brakes".
I have some experience with the Tektro R559 and I can reccomend them, see also this question for some troubleshooting ideas, if you are into something fancy a brief [insert famous search engine owned by and getting your data for the biggest advertising company in the world] search provides results such as the Velo Orange Gran Cru.
An ancient and brief sum-up of available options in 2020 is published here.

Thank you. Great answer. Definitely helps me a lot!
